# Forge viewer model revit position

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm loading multiple models into the viewer but the didn't keep their revit position. Is there a way to load a model at it revit position and rotation ?

Comment: Please try to align models with `globalOffset` and check the util here: https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil If it doesn't help, please consider providing more details about this issue, e.g. snapshots, code snippets and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eason Kang solution did the job. 
To align the model in their Revit position use globalOffset Property when you load the model inside the viewer.